# Getting multiple records in SSIS

Tags: ssis, etl

We are working on a ETL process. The process requires us to take ID from source (Oracle) and query another data source (MS SQL DB). The query needs to get two sets of data

1. Customer details - one to one mapping get all the accounts of the

   1. customer accounts by the relationship id -multiple records for the same id

We are currently using the look-up component and in the process only getting the first match for the customer account. How can we get multiple matching records - i,e all matching customer accounts. Since both datasources are different, we are not able to do an inner join. The other alternative we could think of was to use staging table, but we wanted to avoid this. Is there any other way using SSIS component to get multiple matching records for the same ID.

Comment: What do you want to do with the data later? Add data as derived column and save it to some other table? Mind using multiple Data Sources with proper SQL queries and `Union All` to merge it together.

Comment: After getting it , we need to insert it into destination. The records from 1-1 mapping is different from the records from 1-many. One is customer details and another is customer accounts. I am not sure if we can do Union all.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already identified, the Lookup Component is a Synchronous item. One rows flows through it and only one row comes out. The Lookup and add data to an existing row but can't add a new row into the stream.

Having been in your shoes, except I was working with DB2, I ended up going with an [Asynchronous Script](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136133.aspx). I would pass in the id to the Component in ReadOnly mode and defined my new Output and all the columns that the task will generate. Yes, this is tedious.

Inside my script, in my PreExecute I established a connection to my data source and then in the I'd fire off singleton queries to my database to get all the related accounts. I did two things with the returned data. I called the AddRow method and populated the fields - this sends the data downstream. I also kept a local copy in memory as I could have had the same ID multiple times in a given run (Person bought financial product A and in the same batch, they also bought product B). This would save me a trip to the database. You're in a better position to understand your data and whether this will help or not.