# Multiple matches with Script Component (the Lookup transformation returns only the first match)

Tags: ssis

I've been trying to find a solution to get multiple matches from my reference table, I looked into the following posts but they don't mention a solution that worked, just a possibility of using a script component. As I don't code in C# this gets trick...is there anyone that have an exempel of this transformation?

These are the similar questions I looked:
[Getting multiple records in SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740576/getting-multiple-records-in-ssis)

[How can I get all matching rows from lookup using full cache mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57711501/how-can-i-get-all-matching-rows-from-lookup-using-full-cache-mode)

Anyone has an idea on how to solve it with SSIS?

Here is what I'm trying to achieve:

| Id | GroupCategory | Group | Category |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EEF | Health | Medicine |
| 1 | EEF | Trafic | Bus |
| 1 | EEF | Trafic | Car |
| 1 | EEF | Environment | Threes |

Everyon column in this results resides in a different table and on sql I just do a bunch of joins, meanwhile I've trying to do lookups in SSIS but I just get the first matched row, then I don't get all information about the same Id.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't want C#, the other option requires sorting of your two inputs and then using a [merge join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/transformations/merge-join-transformation?view=sql-server-ver16).

[image]

If you don't explicitly sort your inputs, either in the database (preferred) and mark it as such in the source OR use an explicit sort as shown here, the merge join is going to provide bad output. Maybe some things will match but that's just luck of the draw. It only works if you physically order the data.

Comment: Hi thanks for the help! It's not that I didn't want to use C#, it's just that I don't know how to do it. But I did use merge before you mentioned it and it worked fine, my initial worry was that it would make things slower but it doesn't seem like it.